# Composer require to save patch version in JSON

Tags: php, composer-php

When I run

```
composer require symfony/symfony
```

I have this in my composer JSON:

```
"symfony/symfony": "^2.7"
```

while I would like to have this:

```
"symfony/symfony": "^2.7.6"
```

Can I make composer to save patch (from convention MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH) into composer.json?

If that's not possible then why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, because of convention. In ~ 99% use cases it does not make sense to lock to patch version.

According to [Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), package should be compatible in every minor version. Meaning `2.5` won't break after update from `2.4`.

Software evolves and the less version you need to upgrade, the easier. This is kind of soft enforcement to upgrade (in words: don't be stuck on version `2.4`, if there is `2.15`) and support back package development.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make composer to save patch (from convention MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH) into composer.json?

Here you go: `composer require symfony/symfony:"^2.7.6"`.

Or edit `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/symfony": "^2.7.6"
    }
}
```

Question from comment:

> How to require without writing version and to get the exact latest one written into composer.json?

Composer uses `^major.minor` by default. It will not insert `^major.minor.current-latest-patch-level`.

One could argue that some patch level versions could be skipped by the solver, if a specific start of the patch level range is given. Here versions `2.7.0 to 2.7.5` would be skipped.

On the other hand, specifying `^major.minor` allows maximum interoperability by including the full patch level range, starting at the lowest patch level and then going up.

At least you have the chance to write the specific version requirement on the CLI (see above).

Comment: I know that, I meant to do require without writing version and to get the exact latest one written into composer.json.

Comment: Composer uses "^major.minor" by default. It will not insert "^major.minor.current-latest-patch-level". One could argue that some patch level versions could be skipped by the solver, if a specific start of the patch level range is given. On the other hand "^major.minor" allows maximum interoperability by including the full patch level range starting at the lowest patch level and then going up. At least you have the chance to write the specific version requirement on the CLI.